# How can I remove border from my DatePicker input box?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datepicker

I am working on a react component and using `datePicker` inside it to choose date,When I render my DatePicker component,It shows a Black border outside my text box and I want to remove that border.

Here's my component:

```
     <div className='col'>
        {translateText('ui.label.message.start.date')}
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.props.startDate}
          placeholder={translateText('Start Date')}
          onChange={date => this.handleStartDateChange(date)}
          dateFormat='DD-MM-YYYY'
          customStyles={{ dateInput: { borderWidth: 0 } }}
        />
      </div>
```

I have introuduced customStyles to remove that border but its not working.
Here's a snapshot of my issue:
[image]

Comment: do you have any custom css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no css applied to your input-filed.
You could fix this like:

```
.react-datepicker-wrapper input[type="text"]{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: How can I do it without changing the common css? is there a way I can use customStyles to do it?

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap the component , or try this options I provide here,
please next time write the exact library you use.

```
<div className='col'>
 {translateText('ui.label.message.start.date')}
 <div className="customDatePicker">
   <DatePicker
     wrapperClassName="customDatePicker"
     className="customDatePicker"
     selected={this.props.startDate}
     placeholder={translateText('Start Date')}
     onChange={date => this.handleStartDateChange(date)}
     dateFormat='DD-MM-YYYY'
     />
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for Dec 2023, this solution is working

```
.react-datetime-picker__wrapper {
border: none;
}
```

I looked up in the .css from source code. There is class which has `__wrapper` that has `border: thin solid gray;`